# Function that executes on GUI closing in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am creating a GUI in matlab using guide.  It's non-blocking (not calling `uiwait`).  When the gui window is closed, I would like to execute some clean up code.

Is there an `gui_ClosingFcn` callback I should define in analogy to the `gui_OpeningFcn` template that guide creates for me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figure windows have a [`'DeleteFcn'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#DeleteFcn), which defines a callback function that will run when the window is closed/deleted. You could potentially use that to do your clean-up.

Comment: set(hObject, 'DeleteFcn', @myhandle) in the openingFcn should do the trick then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Figure windows have a `CloseRequestFcn` property, which defines a callback function that will run when the window is closed (before deleting the window).
[image]

Comment: +1 Branching at the close request level is cleaner IMHO as it enables to reuse a `close` function of the enclosing object. That way, the figure can be closed either programmatically or via the GUI through the same function.