# How to load data from previous session / store data from Edit Text Boxes in Matlab guide?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have written a Matlab guide tool. But I need to give a lot of paths every time I start up the tool. Eg

```
/path/to/image/folder
/path/to/annotation/folder
/path/to/filelist1
/path/to/filelist2
```

Right now I have to click all buttons and search for the files manually using `uigetfile` which is tedious. Is there a way such that when I close Matlab guide it saves the last state and opens it again the next time that I use it?

Comment: You would need to do this by saving the data yourself somewhere on the file system and then loading it when you load the GUI.

Comment: Of course one method is to manually choose and save all you need and load the saved data in `OpeningFcn`. But I prefer to wait for a better solution.

Comment: Hmm yeah I guess then the question is rather whether there is a `DeleteFcn`  which is executed when closing the guide window

Comment: lucky you, there is a `DeleteFcn`: The `CloseRequestFcn` from your main figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the previous GUI session is simple: use `hgsave('filename')`.
See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgsave.html

Example:
1. In the CloseRequestFcn callback function, I added hgsave:

```
% --- Executes when user attempts to close figure1.
function figure1_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: delete(hObject) closes the figure
hgsave('test1.fig')

delete(hObject);
```

2. I opened untitled1.fig:
   [image]
3. Modified few GUI controls (include the text edit), and close the GUI.
4. Open test1.fig, and get the last session:
   [image]

Comment: Very good. It works. This link shows how to add the closeRequestFcn Callback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000564/function-that-executes-on-gui-closing-in-matlab